# weird chars after getting value from XML php

Tags: php, xml, special-characters

I'm trying to get a value with a € sing out of xml but when I try it gives back weird code.

```
$xmlDate = $searchNode->getElementsByTagName( "kostenvoorverkoop" );
$valueKostenvoorverkoop = htmlentities($xmlDate->item(0)->nodeValue,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
//gives back Á€10,- instead of €10,-
```

can't find the problem.

```
//XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<price>€10</price>
```

If I leave the htmlentities it gives a completely wierde string like ÁáÙ%10 <---- not exactly this but you know what I mean.

if anyone can help me with this it would help me greatly, thanks in advance.

edit:
found a small work around: change the € for `&amp;euro;`. know not clean but works.

Comment: ISO-8859-1 is completely different from UTF-8...

Comment: ISO-8859-1 **does not contain** the euro character `€`. This means that the encoding declared in XML declaration is incorrect and your XML is technically not well-formed. Probably your document is ISO-8859-15 or windows-1252 (or UTF-8 possibly containing an invalid byte sequence).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<price>€10</price>
```

The character `€` does not exist in ISO-8859-1, so this XML declaration can't possibly be right.

The output `Á€` suggests the file has actually been encoded in Windows code page 1252 (Western European), which is similar to ISO-8859-1 but has different characters in the range 0x80–0x9F, include the euro sign.

PHP has parsed the data as ISO-8859-1, where the CP1252 encoding of `€`, byte 0x80, maps to the control character U+0080. It then gives you the Unicode string containing U+0080 as a UTF-8-encoded byte string, U+00C2,U+0080. Outputting that to a browser in a page served as cp1252, ISO-8859-1 (for tedious confusing legacy reasons) or without a charset on a Western European machine, gives `Á€`. `htmlentities()` doesn't encode this in any way because there's no HTML entity for the control code U+0080.

Here's how you should proceed:

- If you must have your XML input file in cp1252, state that in the XML declaration's `encoding="windows-1252"` rather than the inaccurate `ISO-8859-1`. XML parsers aren't required to be able to read cp1252, though, so better for interoperability would be to just use the default UTF-8 encoding and re-save the file to match.
- Serve your output HTML page as UTF-8, using a `Content-Type` header or meta tag. Then use `htmlspecialchars()` instead of `htmlentities()` so you don't waste time encoding non-ASCII characters that don't need it.

Comment: And a third option if you don't have any control over the input format is to pre-process using [iconv()](http://php.net/iconv).

Comment: I changed it to `encoding="windows-1252"` but I'm still getting the Á in front of the € sign

Comment: found a small work around by sending `&amp;euro;` to the xml. this wil end up being a  € sign. not clean but it works

Comment: If that works you've got potentially bigger problems: HTML-injection. If the XML file could be made to contain `<price>&lt;script>alert()&lt;/script></price>`, it'd end up dropping active scripting into the page, for example. `htmlspecialchars()` and doing everything in UTF-8 are the best approach today.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to change the encoding in the xml from  ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 ?
Or just put in php this charset ISO-8859-1 when you are making the decoding..